# Where does Visual Studio 2019 saves the git comparison file?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

I selected a file to view its history in Git and then I selected two instances to compare them. The file has an option to save but, where does it actually save the file so I can open it and see directly the comparison?[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that whatever changes you make in the diff, are only "doable" to the current version of the file, so you're not saving the "diff" you're actively modifying the current version of the file.

Comment: Check my edit, Render.cshtml is the file's name and VS2019 offers me to save another thing, not the Render.cshtml file itself.

Comment: I would say, launch a search on the file system with the file name... (after having saved).